# Flashing folder with question mark OS X 10.11

Tags: macos, folders, recovery

It seems like I totally messed up my MacBook Pro Retina (15" mid 2014) today. I'll try to tell you the story as short as possible.

My MacBook was encrypted and I decided to dual boot Arch Linux on it. It was a bad idea because while partitioning the drive I made my OS X boot unreadable.

I spent hours and hours trying to fix it and it seemed like I had found a solution. I followed the steps but got an error at some point. Now nothing works, literally nothing.

Only thing I get is the flashing grey folder with a question mark on it. If I press the option key, I get the same flashing folder. Cmd+r (not Recovery HD but network recovery) and cmd+opt+r both work but the globe never stops spinning. Even after over 40 mins, nothing. And it can't be due to my internet, I have 50 Mbps. Files are probably lost at this point too I guess.

Does anybody have any idea what to do?

Edit: somehow pressing opt key now brings me to the bootloader. So not everything is totally broken. I tried making a USB with InstallESD.dmg (extracted from the El Capitan install app) with TransMac on Windows but so far the USB isn't being recognized :/

Comment: If you look up your MacBook model, does it support internet recovery? Can you boot to Disk Utility / instal screen using internet recovery? Please edit that detail into the post. Also, reset the NVRAM and re-test the recovery mode boot.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides support to reinstall the OS. https://apple.com/support and you might have to pay if you are not covered with an exception or AppleCare.

Other options are to try going to an apple store, as they have netboot server (the globe you see on startup) that they can use to recover the computer by putting a new system back on it.